# Hide a Post independently if current_user has marked Post as 'hidden'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been at this for days now without any luck. but I'm trying to allow users to `hide` or mark Posts as `read` independently. But I simply cannot get it to work. Maybe it's because my brain is currently inside-out.

Here's my query:

```
<% 
@posts.includes(:postsettings).where.not(
    postsettings: {user_id: current_user.id}).where(postsettings: 
    {delete_post: true}).each do |post| 
%>
```

What I'm trying to do here is **Exclude** an entire Post IF any of the postsettings includes the **current_user.id** – But as soon as another user also marks it as deleted – It pops back up again for current_user because the criteria is met reversibly.

Everything else is set up correctly to the best of my knowledge, using a join table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. What would be the correct approach?

Comment: If you want it to be persistent, you'll need a separate table with post id and user id. Do a left join, and only show posts where the join fails (column is null). If a user marks a post, add a record to this new table.

Comment: Hi Sloan, thanks for a quick reply. The postsettings has a both user_id and post_id. Could you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, I dont get why you're using two where queries on for relating same object.

```
<% @posts.includes(:postsettings).where.not(
    postsettings: {user_id: current_user.id, delete_post: true}).each do |post| %>
    .....
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, this doesn't present any records at all. Regardless of who the post was created by.